# Access to extern const struct from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mogenerator

I can't access a c-struct from Swift, which was generated with Mogenerator.

The struct is in the implementation:

```
const struct MyAttributes MyAttributes = {
    .foo = @"foo",
};
```

And then in the header:

```
extern const struct MyAttributes {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *foo;
} MyAttributes;
```

I added the header import to the bridging header. But I can't access the struct from Swift. With Objective C I can. I thought maybe Swift needs the struct declaration as it is in the implementation file, so I tried adding the .m file to the bridging header but this doesn't work. I think I can't change the structure of these files because they are generated by Mogenerator.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Or use the swift flag in mogenerater. No need for any bridging then.

Comment: Most of my code is still in Objective C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
#import "YourClass.h"
```

in the bridging header file you can access the struct from Swift as

```
let fooAttr = MyAttributes.foo
println(fooAttr) // Output: "foo"
```

Comment: Hmm this was the first thing I tried and for some reason it didn't work. My code is more complex though, so the reason must be somewhere else. Just tested in a new project and it works.

Comment: I ran into the same thing. I originally though it wasn't working due to the lack of code completion in xcode. Anyone know if there is a way to get the swift code completion working for structs like this?