# Accessing objective-c Struct from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct, constants

I'm working on an ios application that has a mix of swift and obj-c code. One of my obj-c model classes defines a struct containing strings to assist in converting to a dictionary and back. I have the bridging header setup and I can access methods defined in my objective-c class in a swift class. What I can't figure out is how to access the static stuct to get at my property strings. Here is a snippet of my .h and .m files:

**OrderItem.h**

```
extern const struct OrderItemAttributes {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *created;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *created_by_id;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *device_deleted;
} OrderItemAttributes;

@interface OrderItem : NSManagedObject {}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* created;
@end
```

**OrderItem.m**

```
const struct OrderItemAttributes OrderItemAttributes = {
    .created = @"created",
    .created_by_id = @"created_by_id",
    .device_deleted = @"device_deleted",
};

@implementation OrderItem
@dynamic created;
@end
```

I thought I would simply be able to use

> OrderItem.OrderItemAttributes.created

to access the attribute strings but swift doesn't accept that syntax. Is there any way to do what I want without major changes to my objective-c code?

Comment: please, try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947811/swift-method-with-a-swift-enum-as-parameter-is-not-visible-in-objective-c/33954226#33954226

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that wouldn't help in my case. I need to access the struct in swift not the other way around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to extern const struct from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365150/access-to-extern-const-struct-from-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `OrderItemAttributes` isn't part of the `OrderItem` namespace.  It would be accessed directly as:

```
var foo: NSString = OrderItemAttributes.created.takeUnretainedValue()
```

The problem you're seeing with autocomplete occurs because `OrderItemAttributes` is ambiguous; it's both a type name and a variable name. Use different names for the struct type name and the global variable to avoid the ambiguity.  E.g., add 'Struct' to the end of the type name:

```
extern const struct OrderItemAttributesStruct {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *created;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *created_by_id;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *device_deleted;
} OrderItemAttributes;
```